# Spring webflux - Routing

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I am using Spring boot 2.3.3.RELASE and using webflux. Using the below router config.

```
@Bean
public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> itemRoute() {
    return RouterFunctions.route(POST("/api/v1/item").and(accept(APPLICATION_JSON)), itemHandler::createItem)
            .andRoute(GET("/api/v1/item/{itemId}").and(accept(APPLICATION_JSON)), itemHandler::getItemById)
            .andRoute(GET("/api/v1/item/list").and(accept(APPLICATION_JSON)), itemHandler::getItems);
}
```

When I hit `/api/v1/item/1` ---> It works as expected.

But, hitting `/api/v1/list` also goes to `getItemById` instead of `getItems`. `/api/v1/item/list` also considered as `/api/v1/item/{itemId}` and list is coming as itemId.

Anything wrong with this?

Comment: why do you need `/list` at the end of the url? Shouldn't `/api/v1/item` return a list of all items if you are following a restful api design?

Answer (score 2):

Spring documentation for `andRoute`

> Return a composed routing function that routes to the given handler function if this route does not match and the given request predicate applies.

The key word here is **composed**. It means that you can declare multiple routes that all together must match together for the route to trigger.

what you are looking for is probably just using the plain `route` builder function.

Taken example from the spring documentation:

```
RouterFunction<ServerResponse> route = route()
    .GET("/person/{id}", accept(APPLICATION_JSON), handler::getPerson) 
    .GET("/person", accept(APPLICATION_JSON), handler::listPeople) 
    .POST("/person", handler::createPerson) 
    .add(otherRoute) 
    .build();
```

or you could use the `path` builder function is another option.

```
RouterFunction<ServerResponse> route = route()
        .path("/api/person", builder -> builder
            .POST( ...)
            .GET( ... )
            .GET( ... )
        ).build())
    .build()
```

[Webflux Router Function](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-fn-router-functions)

Comment: For list, adding /list to the list api behaves same with this example as well.

Comment: if you want a specific difference between `/list` and `/list/{value}` then you have to do your own null check if the value exists or not because the framework can't figure out your intentions if you want to be able to send an empty value or not. It's not an AI.

Comment: the routes are evaluated in the order they are defined. If you want `/item/list` to map to a unique hander function then define it above the `/item/{item_id}` route definition. Though as stated in another comment, this does not feel restful.